# Can I do multi class classification with apache spark Support Vector Machines?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, apache-spark-mllib

When I tried Apache Spark SVM for a multi class classification problem, I got following error. Can someone explain me whether there is a way to do SVM multi class classification using Apache Spark MLlib

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Input validation failed.
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.run(GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.run(GeneralizedLinearAlgorithm.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.SVMWithSGD$.train(SVM.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.SVMWithSGD$.train(SVM.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.SVMWithSGD.train(SVM.scala)
    at SVMClass.main(SVMClass.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every ML algorithm can handle multiclass problems out of the box. If that's the case, you can always use [one vs. rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#One-vs.-rest) strategy. The Wiki article explains which algorithms have "natural" extension to multiclass.

If you check the [Spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-classification-regression.html) you will notice that SVM's are mentioned under binary. SVM algorithm needs extension to handle multiple classes and apparently it might be not implemented (judging from docs) in MLlib. You can work around that with the mentioned OvR strategy, but your performance won't be stellar. Multilayer perceptron is an interesting alternative, as it can also provide probability of belonging to the given class.